# getting error: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed - multiple linear regression model

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Rshiny, not sure what I am doing wrong..
Basically, I want to build a multiple linear regression model, which can predict values of the uploaded file based on the model build on the mtcars dataset.
This should also allow the user to select the independent variables.
However, when I am doing it then its giving me the error:-
**Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed**

Please find below the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(caret)
library(shiny)
library(curl)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My first predictive model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      uiOutput("dependent"),
      uiOutput("independents"),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("action", "Predict!")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)      
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath)
  })

  output$dependent <- renderUI({
    df <- filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("dependent","Select ONE variable as dependent variable from:",items)
  })
 output$independents <- renderUI({
 df <- filedata()
 if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
 checkboxGroupInput('independents','Select the regressors', choices = names(df))
 })
 #regression formula
 regformula <- reactive({
   as.formula(paste(mpg,'~',output$independents))
 })
 #model
 output$summary1 <- renderPrint({
   input$action
   modelq <- lm(regformula(),data=mtcars)
   pred1<-predict(modelq,df)
   summary(modelq())
   pred1
   })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The probles is that you try to read `outputs$independents` in `regFormula`. Outputs are "write-only" in the server just like inputs are read-only. Maybe use `input$independents` instead?

Comment: When I changed output$independents to input$independents, I am getting this error:-  Error in $<-.reactivevalues: Attempted to assign value to a read-only reactivevalues object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having some data at hand to reproduce your app its hard to spot the error and makes it more of a guessing game.

So my first guess would be, that you're not handling the reactivity in your app correctly. You're render* functions are calling reactive values, but when no file was uploaded and no Regressor was chosen, there is no data to work with, so it will throw an error. I would suggest checking out the Shiny principles of reactivity and the functions `observeEvent, req, validate`.

Then you can remove the lines with `is.null(*)`, as the `req()` function does that for you.

Next thought, what is `mpg`?
And I think you should change `summary(modelq())` to `summary(modelq)` too, as you just want to print the summary of the object and not call the object.

Calling `library(shiny)` once is enough. ;)

In the prediction you are also calling `df`, which is not assigned in that function. I added a `reactiveValues` object, where you can save other objects in a reactive way. And in your second renderUI we add the data to the reactiveValues object like this`df$file <- df`. And in the prediction function you can call the data like this `predict(modelq,df$file)`.

I also changed the `regformula` to an eventReactive() which will be executed every time you press the action button.

And lastly, I changed to formula creation to `as.formula(paste("mpg",'~',paste(input$independents, collapse= "+")))`, as if you only call input$independents, it will only take the first argument.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(caret)
library(curl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My first predictive model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      verbatimTextOutput("smp"),
      uiOutput("dependent"),
      uiOutput("independents"),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("action", "Predict!")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    read.csv(infile$datapath)
  })
  
  df <- reactiveValues(file = NULL)
  
  output$dependent <- renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    df <- filedata()
    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("dependent","Select ONE variable as dependent variable from:",items)
  })
  output$independents <- renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    df <- filedata()
    
    df$file <- df
    
    checkboxGroupInput('independents','Select the regressors', choices = names(df))
  })
  #regression formula
  regformula <- eventReactive(input$action, {
    as.formula(paste("mpg",'~',paste(input$independents, collapse= "+")))
  })
  #model

  output$summary1 <- renderPrint({
    req(regformula())
    req(input$file1)

    modelq <- lm(regformula(),data=mtcars)

    df <- filedata()

    pred1<-predict(modelq,df); 
    names <- df$X
    
    data.frame(X = as.character(names), Prediction = pred1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks so much, its working now, just one question, its giving the predicted value as:  1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
26.08886 20.50602 16.28581 12.24731 12.90598 26.69196 26.84839 25.83979

Comment: however when I am running the predict function in R, its giving the cars name along with predicted value:Datsun 710            Valiant         Merc 450SE Cadillac Fleetwood 
         24.993728          20.208727          12.282264          11.981681 
 Chrysler Imperial           Fiat 128     Toyota Corolla      Toyota Corona 
          9.028157          25.776366          27.861629          24.910411

Comment: any specific reason why this is happening

Comment: I edited my code, so that it will print out the names of the car and the prediction. You were just printing the prediction values, without names.

Comment: thank you so much, this is what exactly was required

Comment: You're welcome, although I still see some problems in the code. The `independents` variable will also show `X` as option, although no X is in the mtcars data, but it is created in the `read.csv` function and you're `dependent` variable is never called. (It is always `mpg`). And lastly, you should make sure, that no varibale is appearing on both sides of the formula equation, as it would throw an error.